# How can I upload file in a new folder in upload folder?

Tags: php, oracle, file-upload

I hope someone can help me on how can I store the file uploaded in a folder inside the upload folder.. the situation is when user upload 3 files, I want it to store in his/her folder.. let say

```
$directory="/upload/".$userID.";
```

When I eliminate the $userID part, it works fine.

the upload process..

```
/*=======================File Upload Process============================*/

            $num_files = count($_FILES['userfile']);
            $saveDirectory = "upload/".$matricNo."/";

            for($x =0; $x < $num_files; $x++)
            {
            $fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$x];
            $tempName = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$x];
            $fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'][$x];
            $fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'][$x];
            $allowed_ext = array ('doc','docx','pdf');
            $file_ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

                if (($_FILES['userfile']['size'][$x] > 1048576) && (in_array($file_ext, $allowed_ext) == false))
                {
                    header('location: student_newSubmission2.php?error=6');
                    exit();
                }
                elseif ($_FILES['userfile']['error'][$x] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) 
                {
                    $query3 = oci_parse($conn,"INSERT INTO upload(uploadID, uploadname, uploadtype, uploadsize, subID) VALUES (seq_uploadID.nextval,'$fileName', '$fileType', '$fileSize',$subID)");
                    $exe3 = oci_execute($query3) or die('Error, query failed');
                    if (move_uploaded_file($tempName, $saveDirectory.$fileName)) 
                    {
                        echo 'File Successfully Uploaded!';
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                    echo 'There was an error whilst uploading the file.';
                    }
                }           
            }   
        /*=======================File Upload End============================*/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `mkdir()`, The mode is 0777 by default, which means the widest possible access to create dynamic folders,

```
        $saveDirectory = "upload/".$matricNo."/";
        
        if(!is_dir($saveDirectory)){
            mkdir($saveDirectory, 0777);
        }
```

Create dir with permission:

```
<?php
    mkdir("/path/to/my/dir", 0700);
?>
```

Syntax:

`bool mkdir ( string $pathname [, int $mode = 0777 [, bool $recursive = false [, resource $context ]]] )`

**pathname :** The directory path.

**mode**: The mode is 0777 by default, which means the widest possible access. **Note**: **mode** is ignored on Windows.

Ref: https://www.php.net/mkdir

Comment: specify permissions also while creating dir.after it might create problem mkdir('dir',0777)